# Ranger is showing Hadoop-ACL used to grant access instead of Ranger-ACL

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-ranger

I have two hiveserver2 instances running. One uses Binary Transport (for HUE), the other uses HTTP transport (for ODBC connections).

I am trying to grant access for one user (ra01 in the screenshot) to only a specific table in Hive.
The user account is intended to be used for ODBC connection from PowerBI.

I set the policy as seen in the screenshot. The policy seems to work if I try it in HUE but if I use the same user via ODBC, it seems to grant all permissions and it is using "Hadoop-ACL" instead of "Ranger-ACL" as seen in the attached screenshot.

What am I missing?

[image: Ranger Audit Screen]

[image: Ranger policy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue is with the folder permissions in HDFS.
I followed the instructions in the link below; it fixed the issue for me:

[Best practices in HDFS authorization with Apache Ranger](https://blog.cloudera.com/best-practices-in-hdfs-authorization-with-apache-ranger/)